# Why different result with PCA and SVD in Matlab?

Tags: matlab, pca, eigenvector, eigenvalue

I have implemented my PCA function in Matlab in the following way:

```
function e = myPCA(X)
[D, N] = size(X);
m = mean(X, 2);
X = X - repmat(m, 1, N);
[e, ~, ~] = svd(X,'econ');
end
```

When I use now the built in Matlab function `[e, ~, ~] = pca(X');` I'm getting the same absolute values as with my function but for some columns of U the sign is flipped.

Which ones is the right way to go and why is there this difference in sign?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is true that the matrix you denote by `e` has columns which are the basis in which the covariance matrix is diagonal, as should be in PCA. However, an orthogonal basis stays an orthogonal basis if you flip any basis vector. For example, in 2D if the basis `e` you find via Matlab's `pca` is the axes `x` and `y`, then `-x` and -`y` is also a basis. Or stated slightly different, since for `pca` you find the eigenvectors of the covariance matrix, and since if `v` is an eigenvector then `-v` is also an eigenvector (with the same eigenvalue), we see that the principal components are defined up to a sign. Since `svd` and `pca` are implemented differently, you don't have a guaranty to get the same signs.

Comment: Thank you very much. I'm interested in retrieving all the eigenvalues and eigenvectors of the covariance matrix. If I'm using Matlab's pca method the eigenvectors are the columns in "e" from [e, ~, ~] = pca(X');. Is this right? But how can I retrieve the eigenvalues?

Comment: I have another point: "Compute the Principal components and eigenvalues of the Covariance/Correlation matrix". Are the principal components equal to the eigenvectors? Should I use in this case the pca method or SVD method from Matlab or does it not matter?

Comment: Yes, the eigenvectors are the principal components. It does not matter what method you use, they are mathematically equivalent.

Comment: As for the eigenvalues, if the svd decomposition is `x=U*S*V'` (where `'` stands for 'transpose'), then the covariance matrix is `x*x'/n = U*S^2*U'/n`, where `n` is the number of samples. So you see that the eigenvalues are the singular values squared (up to a constant)

Comment: Thank you. Is it also true that I can retrieve the eigenvalues by [e, ~, eigenvalues] = pca(X');?